# React: Removing a class styling after componentWillUpdate

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flux

How do you remove class after component becomes updated? For example,

```
//fire update where fieldname is array of changed fields
componentWillUpdate(){
   $(`.input-${fieldName}`).addClass('highlight');
}
```

I want to fire this function after the event handler gets clicked

```
removeFields (fieldName) {
     //remove highlight updated field name when it is updated
     $(`.input-${fieldName}`).removeClass('highlight');
}
```

Comment: Just add `<input className={updated ? 'highlight' : ''} />` or something like that. You should remove jQuery from your project if you don't need problems.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible if there were over 100 fields that I need to change. I am trying to do do it dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should not make use of `jQuery` to update the DOM element that was rendered using `React`.

**Why:** The reason is `React` renders the components as and when the `state`/`props` changes. This re-rendering would overwrite the changes made by `jQuery` and will leave you helpless.

**Solution:** Maintain a state for every logical action you need to take.

In your case, you need to maintain a `boolean` `state` variable to indicate if the component is updated or not. Initially it would be false if your constructor(similar to below).

```
constructor() {
 this.state = {
  isUpdated: false
 }
}
```

When your logic hits, update this state variable to true using `this.setState({isUpdated: true})` and when the event handler make it to false using `this.setState({isUpdated: false})` so it would be false when the event occurs.

Finally in your render method, make use of this variable to determine if the classname has to be added to the DOM element or not like

```
 render() {
  // ....
  <input className={`input-myField ${this.state.isUpdated ? 'highlight' : ''}`} />
  // ....
 }
```

If you are using too much of logic to handle `classNames` then i suggest you use [this library](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

Comment: Note that you cannot call this.setState() here. If you need to update state in response to a prop change, use componentWillReceiveProps() instead. (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

Comment: @Manolo, that is right one should not use `setState` in `componentWillUpdate` .

Comment: How would you call componetWillRecieveProps if I need to update the state?